# What is a lava cast?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, terminology

I see references in youtube videos to "lava casts" which seem to be large, quick-to-build, wedge-shaped structures made of cobblestone, often used for griefing on anarchy servers.  I can't find a good reference to what they are or how they are built.  Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

From what I can tell from experimenting and searching.

You need a bucket of water, a bucket of lava and some basic blocks (e.g. cobblestone).

Build a staircase structure out of your blocks, and use your lava bucket to place a lava source block on top of it, the lava will cascade down the structure and over the sides producing a wedge-shaped structure of lava. Make sure you are standing in a safe place when you do this!

Then use your now empty bucket to remove the lava source block (lava is valuable!) and replace it with a water source block, the water will cascade down the structure turning the lava to cobblestone as it goes.

Comment: And … what for?

Comment: The aim seems to be a quick way to make large ugly structures that are more of a pain to remove than they are to build,

Comment: Then I do not think that making a tutorial for it is particularly helpful.

Comment: Lava casting has been made into artform on anarchy servers. This post gives just  the simplest initial step of making lava casts. Afterwards the structure can be expanded into a pyramid (utilizing the newly formed cobble "stairs" on the side), and with careful guiding of lava flow, the resulting structures can be quite fancy; customizing them, leaving empty spaces inside to form hidden bases, with moderate effort you can build a massive structure that is very hard to grief. Being very common they are a good method of hiding more valuable objects "in plain sight" by covering them in lava cast.

Comment: FitMC's 'abandoned highway' video features some awesome lava casts. [9:37](https://youtu.be/ec4wV6wBnTw?t=577) - a monumental pyramid at 50th kilometer of the highway.  [11:30](https://youtu.be/ec4wV6wBnTw?t=690) an example of an artistic lava cast base.